# Location of Angular Snippets in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: angular, visual-studio

I keep running into these Angular snippets in Visual Studio 2017. I would like to delete them because I don't use Angular at all. I've deleted a bunch of angular snippets from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\JS\xxx\snippets folders but they still show up.

How can I remove these from Visual Studio 2017?

[image]
[image]

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y3kkate1.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around I finally found the fix.

Tools > Options > Text Editor > JavaScript/TypeScript > Language Service...

Uncheck 'Enable the new JavaScript language service'.